# string inside txt file not equal checksum file

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5

I have a problem comparing the md5 generated by a file and comparing it if it is present within a list.

I generate MD5

```
def hash_file(file_path, hash_file_txt):
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    a_file = open(file_path, 'rb')
    content = a_file.read()
    md5_hash.update(content)
    digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
    line = str(digest)
    f = open(hash_file_txt, 'a')
    f.write(f'{line}\n')
    f.close()
    return True
```

The function I use for comparison

```
string_to_search = '8ad51ef12208617a91a201c69e9b7d92' 
def check_if_string_in_file_md5(hash_logs_file, string_to_search):
    with open(hash_logs_file, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            strings = (str(string_to_search))
            other_strings = (str(line))
            if strings == other_strings:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I tried to modify the two parameters `strings == other_strings` with two variables containing the same content and it works. The problem is when I go to read the lines inside the `hash_logs_file` which still contains the same string. Comparing it, it is not the same

Comment: You're returning on the first iteration of the loop. You're just checking whether the first line matches.

Comment: `line` ends with a newline character. Does `string_to_search` end with newline?

Comment: you can also try doing just a `return string_to_search in read_obj.read()`

Comment: you should remove `else: return False` from `for`-loop and use `return False` after `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You check only first line - use `return False` after `for`-loop when you checked all lines.

And you should use `strip()` to remove `'\n'` from `line`

```
string_to_search = '8ad51ef12208617a91a201c69e9b7d92' 

def check_if_string_in_file_md5(hash_logs_file, string_to_search):
    with open(hash_logs_file, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            line = line.strip() # remove '\n'
            if line == string_to_search:
                return True
        
        # - after loop -
        return False
```